# Select Sold and unsold product from same table in SQL Server for last month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have Database table and trying to write query to find sold and not sold product list from one table.

Table is Below

[image]

Expecting Result

[image]

How do i get this result? i am using CTE to create Tamp table and with all services and then do left join but it dose give me only product sold in Feb, but i want all product with no sell too.

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). It's even easier for us to help you if you show us the query you wrote. And the DDL for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cross join the products and the dates, and then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
select 
    p.product,
    t.quantity_sold,
    d.yr,
    d.mn
from (select distinct product from mytable) p
cross join (select distinct yr, mn from mytable) d
left join mytable t
    on  t.product = p.product
    and t.yr = d.yr
    and t.mn = d.mn
```

This puts `null`s for rows with no sale - that's presumably a numeric column so you generally don't want to write a string like `'Not Sold'` into it.

If there is a possibility of duplicate `(product, yr, mn)`, you might want to use outer aggregation:

```
select 
    p.product,
    sum(t.quantity_sold) quantity_sold,
    d.yr,
    d.mn
from (select distinct product from mytable) p
cross join (select distinct yr, mn from mytable) d
left join mytable t
    on  t.product = p.product
    and t.yr = d.yr
    and t.mn = d.mn
group by p.product, d.yr, d.mn
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot and resolve my problem